# Proxy'ing a "throw exception"

Tags: java

Suppose I have the code below that needs to throw an exception from withing an anonymous function without modifying the function:

```
FOO.doSomething(new Transactable(){
 public void run(FOO foo) {
     // How to proxy a exception throw
     // from here, without modifying the class
 }
});
```

Like:

```
@Override
public void run() throws MyCustomException{
       FOO.doSomething(new Transactable(){
           public void run(FOO foo) {
               // How to proxy a exception throw
               // from here, without modifying the class
           }
        });             
}
```

Comment: So wait you want the exception thrown from the anonymous class to be actually thrown by the parent method?

Comment: And what do you mean by "without modifying the function"? It seems to me that you are the one implementing the `run` method, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some doubts that I understood this correctly, but here's my shot. I guess you're trying to somehow move the exception from the anonymous class and throw it from the parent method:

```
class ExceptionWrapper {
    public Exception exception;
}

@Override
public void run() throws MyCustomException{
       final ExceptionWrapper ew = new ExceptionWrapper();

       FOO.doSomething(new Transactable(){
           public void run(FOO foo) {
               try {
                   ...
               } catch(MyCustomException ex) {
                   ew.exception = ex;
               }
           }
        });             

        if(ew.exception != null) throw (MyCustomException)ew.exception;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, however, one issue I see is that the run() function may not return right away, so the exception ew may be null and the run() function will just return with the exception wrapper being null?

Comment: @xybrek: So it's executed on a different thread? Doesn't `run` return before `doSomething`?

Comment: This application runs on Google Appengine (GAE) and from the docs, in Appengine we can't create new thread

Comment: If that's the case it means doSomething() must return before the if-statement is executed from the code above?

Comment: @xybrek: Yes, since you are calling `doSomething` it will return before the `if` is evaluated.